# I'm looking for a word to describe repeated pattern that happen at fixed intervals

Tags: single-word-requests

People use our website only on Mondays, what word can I use to describe this behaviour.

Example usage:

> The ________ of users is to visit the website on Mondays.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, added an example usage

Comment: Why does "pattern" not work?

Comment: The indicated duplicate is not exactly what the OP is looking for. Let's reopen.

Comment: @fev That the OP in this question has chosen to phrase it differently doesn't mean it isn't a duplicate. :) BTW, I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: The answer 'routine' admittedly only appears as a modifier in an answer in the previous string: 'a sequence of recurring routine or repetitive actions or events; a period of time that recurs in a fixed pattern'.

Comment: A "round" is not a routine. Routine is about a _**pattern of behaviour**_ not about the process itself, with which the indicated duplicate is concerned. None of the suggested answers there works in this sentence.

Comment: @fev We could avoid bloat by yout adding 'routine' and/or 'routinely' to your answer at the previous question. The _title questions_ are duplicates.

Comment: *The pattern of users is to visit the website on Mondays.*

Comment: If you're looking at it as a behaviour, I would say maybe "habit".... fev's answer upvoted : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Routine*:

> your usual way of doing things, especially when you do them in a fixed order at the same time
>
> - Staying at your desk until 7.30 pm has become ***routine***. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/routine_1))

Comment: thanks for your response, can't upvote this, not enough reputation!!

Comment: @indian-redbull You can accept the answer by clicking on the tick.

Comment: "Routine" implies that it is the same users repeatedly visiting the site on Mondays. It might be all different people who go to the site once, but usually on Mondays. That would not be "routine".